# ArrayList Class in VBScript: "Type mismatch" error using CopyTo(Array) Method

Tags: arraylist, vbscript, syntax-error, type-mismatch

I'm trying to copy an entire ArrayList to an one-dimensional Array, starting at the beginning of the target array, but I'm getting the error "Type mismatch". I googled a lot and tried different version of the code bellow but anyone worked.

```
Option Explicit
dim arr1, arr2(), iLoop, lenght

Set arr1 = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

for iLoop = 0 to 3
arr1.add iLoop
next

redim arr2(arr1.count)

arr2 = arr1.ToArray()

for iLoop = 0 to ubound(arr2)
msgbox "arr2: " & arr2(iLoop)
next
```

Comment: I'm guessing the `arr2 = arr1.ToArray()` is going to be the problem VBScript Arrays are not the same as .Net Arrays, everything in VBScript is a [subtypes of `Variant`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9e7a57cf(v=vs.84).aspx) data type.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `toArray` method/function in [VBScript](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t0aew7h6(v=vs.84).aspx). Reference found (with examples) for instance in

- [`toArray` Method (VBArray)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc634c13(v=vs.94).aspx) (JavaScript) or
- [`toArray` Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8943ay3x(v=vs.90).aspx) (Visual Studio - JScript) or
- [`toArray` Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc634c13(v=vs.84).aspx) (Windows Scripting - JScript)

For more guidance on [`ArrayList` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist(v=vs.110).aspx) and its usage in VBScript please read

- [Ekkehard.Horner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/603855/ekkehard-horner)'s answer [The correct way to use an ArrayList Of Arrays if you just need read access (after a successful initialization)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19916036/3439404)
- Hey, Scripting Guy! article [Be Careful What You Say](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/2007.01.heyscriptingguy.aspx)

Here's my digest of Ekkehard.Horner's answer: although a Variant variable containing an `ArrayList` is conceptually different from an `array` variable, one could read them in analogous way using `for .. to .. next` loop or `for each .. in .. next` loop. And my  contribution:

```
option explicit
On Error GoTo 0
Dim sRslt: sRslt = Wscript.ScriptName     ' result

dim arr1, arr2(), iLoop, lenght, oLoop

Set arr1 = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
for iLoop = 0 to 3
  arr1.add Chr( 65 + iLoop)
next

redim arr2(arr1.count -1)
sRslt = sRslt & vbNewLine & "IsArray(arr1)=" & IsArray(arr1) & " arr1.count=" & arr1.count
sRslt = sRslt & vbNewLine & "arr1.type: " & VarType(arr1) & vbTab & TypeName(arr1)
sRslt = sRslt & vbNewLine & "arr2.type: " & VarType(arr2) & vbTab & TypeName(arr2)
'arr2 = arr1.ToArray()

sRslt = sRslt & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "''' for iLoop = 0 to arr1.count -1" 
for iLoop = 0 to ubound(arr2) ' or equivalent 
                              ' for iLoop = 0 to arr1.count -1
  'msgbox "arr2: " & arr2(iLoop)
  arr2(iLoop) = Chr( 97 + iLoop) & arr1(iLoop)
  sRslt = sRslt & vbNewLine & iLoop & " arr1(iLoop): " & arr1(iLoop) _
                            & vbTab &  "arr2(iLoop): " & arr2(iLoop)
next

sRslt = sRslt & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "''' for each oLoop in arr2"
iLoop = 0
for each oLoop in arr2
  sRslt = sRslt & vbNewLine & iLoop & " arr1(iLoop): " & arr1(iLoop) _ 
                            & vbTab & "oLoop: " & oLoop
  iLoop = iLoop + 1
Next

Wscript.Echo sRslt
```

and its output:

```
==> cscript D:\VB_scripts\SO\37052791.vbs
37052791.vbs
IsArray(arr1)=False arr1.count=4
arr1.type: 9    ArrayList
arr2.type: 8204 Variant()

''' for iLoop = 0 to arr1.count -1
0 arr1(iLoop): A        arr2(iLoop): aA
1 arr1(iLoop): B        arr2(iLoop): bB
2 arr1(iLoop): C        arr2(iLoop): cC
3 arr1(iLoop): D        arr2(iLoop): dD

''' for each oLoop in arr2
0 arr1(iLoop): A        oLoop: aA
1 arr1(iLoop): B        oLoop: bB
2 arr1(iLoop): C        oLoop: cC
3 arr1(iLoop): D        oLoop: dD

==>
```